# data table responsive not working properly css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have data tables in my web page. I need to make them responsive. For that i have used the code from this site `http://mobifreaks.com/coding/responsive-data-tables-jquery/`. But it didn't work and also affected my table's normal design. How to make the data table responsive? Any Suggestions?

Comment: a good place to start maybe ,would be [this post](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/) ... has some suggestions. But you should maybe show us some code ... how it didn't work... and people might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

did you include the JQuery library ?? if not you can download it from here http://jquery.com/download/